# How to retrieve the selection index for the selection(s) made on the org.eclipse.jface.viewers.CheckBoxTreeViewer

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, jface

There is no direct method to retrieve the selection index (LIKE getSelectionIndex() } for the selection(s) made on org.eclipse.jface.viewers.CheckBoxTreeViewer.

Comment: getSelection() returns the list of highlighted items but no method exists for retrieving the selection indexes of the selected item in the Tree Viewer .

Comment: Trees don't have a selection index

Comment: @greg-449:  Actually I'm wanna perform a search functionality for my tree items. My Tree view has 'n' number of items and I need to locate the items (by performing  a SEARCH OPERATION and the search should happen after the item that has been selected or highlighted) .

Comment: for this to happen I badly need of the selection index to traverse

Comment: @greg-449 : No way is there to accomplish this ?

Comment: I still don't see why you need a selection index. `getSelection()` gives you the selected items.

Comment: @greg-449: Hi Greg, Thanks anyways !!. I'll try to find some other alternatives to achieve this.